Cranks, starts, cuts out
I have a 2008 petrol golf 1.4 in for repair There are no dash lights coming on. When you crank engine it will turn over and start and cuts out. It seems to be immobilizer kicking in. I took out clocks to see if any dampness had got in as car had just been valeted and seats were very wet. all was dry there. I didn't plug in yet as it was late this evening. Could it be a key problem. No ignition light or any dash lights coming on but all Lights outside, wipers etc working.

Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Under most situations, immobilizers turn on or flash an indicator that you state zero dash lights. What does "took out clocks" and 'valeted" mean? Was this vehicle soaked inside, possibly damaging electrical/electronic circuits? Did you check for blown fuses?
